# Jsoup program type already present

Tags: java, android, jsoup, build.gradle

I am using JSoup to parse my HTML response in my Java application but when I add the implementation I get the following:

> Program type already present: org.jsoup.Connection$KeyVal
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   org.jsoup.Connection$KeyVal, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

I am wondering has anyone experienced this before? I will add my full build.gradle below, I am running the most current SDK.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
       android {    compileSdkVersion 28    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "uareloadedapp"
       minSdkVersion 26
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"    }    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }    }    productFlavors {    } }
       dependencies {    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    implementation (name: 'wikitudesdk', ext:'aar')    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.1.0'    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15.2'    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
       } repositories {    flatDir{
       dirs 'libs'    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is anything that you have added as a dependency and is also in the libs folder. That was my problem. deleting the file from the lib folder fixed it